# Adding a Slider or Carousel in an app in Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow, intel-xdk

I'm trying to make an app for my university project in **Intel XDK** and added sliders which doesn't work. I have tried different sliders some even from **www.responsiveslides.com** but its not working. Can anyone tell me about any specific slider that would work in XDK ?

Comment: all sliders work in xdk...
you need to give more details about what not working.. do you have errors in the console? what device? and browser? etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try using App Framework and the App Starter tool that [you will find here:](http://appstarter.app-framework-software.intel.com). The tool will generate code for you that you can then use in your app.